# Frequency response of accelerometer MMA7361L

Tags: accelerometer, mems, model

In order to create the model of the MEMS accelerometer [MMA7361L](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA7361L.pdf) I'm going to need the frequency response of it, but I don't have access to the university lab to use the oscilloscope because of the pandemic and I don't have one at home. Has anyone profiled the frequency response of the MMA7361L before?

Comment: It's in the data sheet under "Bandwidth Response"

Comment: @Andyaka can't see it ? which page please ?

Comment: How do you search for matching words in a pdf document?

Comment: Oh thank you @Andyaka I was dump to think that there might be a frequency response somewhere I couldn't see, actually it doesn't solve my probleme but I'm hopfull you could help, the information given in the self test is about deltag my goal is find out where the outliers are in order to try to find a circuit which can compensate them , and this to  make a model of the accecelerometer.